# Calling a Javascript Function In a Module Type Script From A Normal Script

Tags: javascript, function, module

I am wondering if there is a way to call a Javascript Function that is inside a Module-type script from a normal script.

**For example:**

HTML:

```html
<body>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
</body>
```

Normal Script:

```js
function myFunction() {
   alert("Calling Module Function!");
   moduleFunction();
}
```

Module Script:

```js
/// Module stuff that requires this to be a module script

function moduleFunction() {
   alert("This was called from inside a module script");
   // Info only accessible inside module script
}
```

I have tried the above code on my site, and I only get an `Uncaught Reference` error that the function name is not defined. Are there more steps I must take in order to use functions throughout the scripts?

Thanks!

Comment: JS modules/libraries all `export` something you need to `import`, whether it's individual methods or an object that provides those methods.  How have you `import`ed the the module/library?

Comment: @jmargolisvt No, I have not. Should I import the function? Maybe `import { moduleFunction } from ...`? I don't know what the from would be because these are all in one HTML file.

Answer (score 4):

Bob, If I understand your problem, and if I have anticipated what you are trying to accomplish, the solution is an easy one.

If you have code, a function say, in a script you have typed as module, this function is not available within the html file that has included the module script and calls a function within the module.

```
 <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

and the function myFunction is declared in main.js. If you try to call myFunction you will get the error you mentioned "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ( with line number in html file where the function was invoked )"

The function is out of scope. Simply write at the end of main.js

```
window.myFunction = myFunction;
```

the anchor element NOW has scope of the function as it is in window namespace.

This may not be the issue you came across, but it is head-slapper if you miss it.

Alex

Comment: This solved my problem and which was the same one as OP.